# Should I use time based indexes for non-log data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

For example, if I want to store orders/booking information then I can use order creation date to index data into “order-yyyy” index. But is there any benefits in doing so? For log data using such indexes is a good idea because it is easier to remove old logs. But what about regular and also somewhat time-based data? I want to keep orders data forever.

So far I’ve come up with this: the only reason to do this is that each year this strategy will allow to automatically scale cluster and prepare it for new data, which will probably improve performance. But intuition suggests that manual fine grained  resharding when it’s needed will be much better approach, and I better to stick with “orders-vX” naming schema (in case of mapping changes).

Answer (score 0):

rather than think about non-log data, think about it being time based. in that way log data is no different to order data, it's just a timestamp with extra info, and Elasticsearch doesn't really worry about it being either

that aside, yes it's 100% a good idea to approach it in the same manner. I would suggest using [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) to manage your indices.